# Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition. Some guidance please

Tags: sql-server

Looking how to clone a database programmatically I found this  great reference:
[Clone a SQL Server database programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38124212/clone-a-sql-server-database-programmatically)

Unfortunately, the solution has errors.

The first error was easily found: The author had created a procedure with one name but called it with a different name. By replacing "dbo.resware_tmp_restore" with "dbo.tmp_restore" the problem was solved.

```
    BACKUP DATABASE [PaydayWeb] TO DISK = 'c:\Temp\aaaa.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY;
    if (objectProperty(object_id('tmp_restore'), 'IsProcedure') is not null)
        drop procedure dbo.tmp_restore
    GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.tmp_restore
        @backup_path NVARCHAR(MAX)
    AS
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON;
        RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM DISK = @backup_path
    END
    GO
    CREATE TABLE #TEMP(
        LogicalName VARCHAR(64),            PhysicalName VARCHAR(130),
        [Type] VARCHAR(1),                  FileGroupName VARCHAR(64),
        Size DECIMAL(20, 0),                MaxSize DECIMAL(25,0), 
        FileID bigint,                      CreateLSN DECIMAL(25,0), 
        DropLSN DECIMAL(25,0),              UniqueID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,  
        ReadOnlyLSN DECIMAL(25,0),          ReadWriteLSN DECIMAL(25,0),
        BackupSizeInBytes DECIMAL(25,0),    SourceBlockSize INT,
        filegroupid INT,                    loggroupguid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        differentialbaseLSN DECIMAL(25,0),  differentialbaseGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
        isreadonly BIT,     ispresent BIT,  TDEThumbpr DECIMAL)
    Insert into #TEMP exec dbo.tmp_restore @backup_path = 'c:\Temp\aaaa.bak';
    GO
    DECLARE @NameData VARCHAR(64)
    DECLARE @NameLog VARCHAR(64)
    Set @NameData = (Select LogicalName from #TEMP t where t.Type like 'D')
    Set @NameLog = (Select LogicalName from #TEMP t where t.Type like 'L')
    RESTORE DATABASE [PaydayWeb_Temp] FROM DISK = 'c:\Temp\aaaa.bak'
        WITH RECOVERY,
        MOVE @NameData TO 'path_Data.mdf',
        MOVE @NameLog TO 'path_Log.ldf'
    GO
    DROP TABLE #TEMP
```

The second error caused a yet unsolved problem. Once I replaced "OldDBName", "NewDBName" and "path" with the appropriate names, I got these error messages:

[image: Once I replaced "OldDBName", "NewDBName" and "path" with the appropriate names, I got these error messages:]

Any suggestions? Thank you very much.

Comment: Take a look at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/restore-statements-filelistonly-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) and you will see that the `RESTORE` operation returns far more columns now so you will need to update your temp table to match. But this shows why this procedure is brittle, and if Microsoft ever change the return from that operation, you will need to update this script again.

Comment: That procedure does nothing particularly useful. Just a risk you accept by grabbing random (and quite old) code from the internet if it doesn't work (or worse). For this to be successful, YOU need to understand how a database and its physical files are associated, how to backup and restore, how to move or rename those files, etc. It is not quite as simple as you might think. And before you do anything, make sure you have good backups of your databases and have a disaster recovery plan that works.

Comment: Also note this restore proc assumes there is only one data and log file, and will break otherwise. It's not difficult for fix the errors but you'll need a separate proc for each SQL version due to changes in the `RESTORE FILELISTONLY` results.

Comment: Thank you DavidG. There was an additional field.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, Dan. In the current case there is only one data file and one log file.

Comment: Well SMor, I need to clone a database several times to use during development.